# Python: file object as function argument

Tags: python, file, function, argument-passing

I have written a function  (`read()`)  in a module I want to import in my main script: this function simply reads a file with Regular Expressions and creates an array from it.

The only parameter this function takes is the file (.txt, only numbers) it has to read.
I would like to open the file in my main script  `data = open('output99.txt', 'r')` giving the file the object `data` and then pass the file object `data` to the function, so that I can change the input file whenever I want..could that be a problem?
Because if I do so, the function doesn't work, and returns an empty array:

```
def read(data):

n_lines = sum(1 for line in data)
array = np.empty((n_lines,13))
re_re = re.compile('^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)')

i=0
for line in data:
    reg = re_re.search(line)
    if(re!=None):
        array[i,0] = reg.group(1)
        array[i,1] = reg.group(2)
        array[i,2] = reg.group(3)
        array[i,3] =  reg.group(4)
        array[i,4] =  reg.group(5)  
        array[i,5] = reg.group(6)
        array[i,6] = reg.group(7)
        array[i,7] = reg.group(8)
        array[i,8] = reg.group(9)       
        array[i,9] = reg.group(10)
        array[i,10] = reg.group(11)
        array[i,11] = reg.group(12)
        array[i,12] = reg.group(13)

    i+=1



return array
```

If I open the file inside the function, it works correctly, but it would be far less quick when i want to change input file. Can anyone explain me that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is not a file name; it's a `file` object. When you read from it using

```
sum(1 for line in data)
```

you read the entire contents of the file, so that the file pointer is at the end of the file. When you try to read from it again with

```
for line in data:
```

you get no data, because you've already read everything in the file. To fix, you'll have to reset the file pointer after you count the number of lines with

```
data.seek(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. And sorry, I will change 'file name' with 'file object' in my question