# Dictionary returned empty from function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm writing a function that takes in a fasta file that may have multiple sequences and returns a dictionary with the accession number as the key and the full length header as the value. When I run the function, I get an empty dictionary, but when I run the same code outside of a function, I get the desired dictionary. I assume this means that somewhere in the function my dictionary is being overwritten with nothing, because if it had to do with my regex pattern the code wouldn't work outside the function either, but I can't seem to find where the dictionary might be getting reset. I tried doing some searching for a solution, but the only questions I found with the same problem had obvious problems (no return value or one of the input variables was overwritten).

here is my function code and output (assume re is imported):

```
def getheader(file):
    '''
    compiles headers from a fasta file into a dictionary

    Parameters
    ----------
    file : file
        file that contains the sequences with headers and has not been read

    Returns
    -------
    dictionary with acc no as key and full header as value

    '''
    head_dict = {}

    for line in file:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            acc = re.search(">([^\s]+)", line).group(1)
            header = line.rstrip()
            head_dict[acc] = header
        
    return head_dict

file = open("seq1.txt", "r")
head_dict = getheader(file)
print(head_dict)
```

output

```
{}
```

Here is the input/output when I run it outside of a function:

```
import re
file = open("seq1.txt", "r")
head_dict = {}

for line in file:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        key = re.search(">([^\s]+)", line).group(1)
        value = line.rstrip()
        head_dict[key] = value


print(head_dict)
```

output

```
{'AF12345': '>AF12345 test sequence 1'}
```

where seq1.txt is the following without the quotes and the txt file has an actual return instead of "\n", I just wasn't sure how to format it correctly.

> ">AF12345 test sequence 1\nCGATATTCCCATGCGGTTTATTTATGCAAAACTGTGACGTTCGCTTGA"

The above is where my code is now. Prior to this I had a function that created two dictionaries and returned a specific one based on an input argument. One dictionary was the accession number and sequences, and the other was this dictionary I'm trying to create now. I did not have any problem getting the first dictionary returned. So I decided to split the function and have one for each dictionary despite it seeming repetitive. I've also tried moving the `head_dict[key] = value` to outside the conditional statement, and got the same problem. I've tried changing the variable names from `key` to `acc` and from `value` to `header`, but still got the same result (you can see in my example outside the function that the variables were originally `key` and `value`). I just tried making the empty dictionary an argument so that it is initialized outside of the function, but I still get an empty dictionary returned. I'm not sure what to try now. Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm sure this can be solved more efficiently with another library, but this is for a class and the instructor is very against using other libraries. We have to learn how to do it ourselves first.

Edit: Now I'm frustrated. I rewrote the code to add in creating the input file for people to use to run my code and help me with it, but it works. I'm sorry to have wasted everyone's time. Here is what I rewrote. If you notice a difference between this and what I posted above, please let me know.

```
import re
def getheader(file):
    '''
    compiles headers from a fasta file into a dictionary

    Parameters
    ----------
    file : file
        file that contains the sequences with headers and has not been read

    Returns
    -------
    dictionary with acc no as key and full header as value

    '''
    head_dict = {}
    
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            acc = re.search(">([^\s]+)", line).group(1)
            header = line.rstrip()
            head_dict[acc] = header
            
    return head_dict

file = open("bookishbubs_test1.txt", "w")
file.write(">AF12345 test sequence 1\nCGATATTCCCATGCGGTTTATTTATGCAAAACTGTGACGTTCGCTTGA")
file.close()

file = open("bookishbubs_test1.txt", "r")
headers = getheader(file)
print(headers)
file.close()
```

Comment: Please add how you are using the function to your [mre].

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: @wwii did fixing the indentation address this for you? Now you should be able to see the bit of code that calls the function, which is what I think you are asking for.

Comment: it should work. Unless the input file is wrong. A [mcve] could be created just by passing a hardcoded list of file lines, so people can reproduce it at home

Comment: Your function works for me - cannot reproduce.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the input file, but I'm not sure why. When I rewrote the code adding the new file to be written, calling the function worked as expected. But then I called the function with one of my test case files, and I got the same issue: an empty dictionary. I also think it's weird that the same file will work when the for loop is not in the function, but doesn't work when the for loop is in the function.

Comment: I figured it out! I realized there must be something wrong with how I'm pulling the file into the function, so that gave me a new phrase to google. The issue was that I was calling the function twice. So when I called it a second time, the file had already been read and pointer was at the end of the file. I added a line to reset the pointer at the beginning of the function per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491259/python-file-object-as-functiion-argument)